# Is there a scope to allow me to show only products with variants with stock?

Tags: spree

I'd like to change the "products" overview of my Spree 3.0.x shop to show only products that have one or more variants that can be supplied. This would be on top of the normal scopes (available, with price in current currency).
It would also affect the taxonomy-listings.

I don't want to affect the search page, though: when searching, unavailable products should show up.

As far as I can see, there is no such scope, neither on `Spree:Product` nor on `Spree::Product scopes.rb`.

If there is no such scope, what would be the proper chain of `joins`- and `includes` to write this scope on `Product`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably start with something like:

```
Spree::Product.joins(
  variants_including_master: :stock_items
).group('spree_products.id').having("SUM(count_on_hand) > 0")
```

That should give you close to what you're looking for.

Comment: That is a start. But it does not take into account the items that are backorderable or variants that have `track_inventory` set to false or are `backorderable`. The query I came up with is `joins(:stock_items).where("count_on_hand > ?  OR #{Spree::Variant.table_name}.track_inventory = ? OR backorderable = ?", 0, false, true).distinct`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension:

https://github.com/swrobel/spree_zero_stock_products/

By default it just adds a scope to `Spree::Product` without changing the default search scope. You can use the provided `:on_hand` scope at convenience.

Comment: The extension gave me the information needed. But itself is both out of date (I use Spree 3.0.x) and both trivial to reimplement yet not entirely what I need. I took some code from it and implemented myself.

Comment: @berkes can you share your implementation please ?